# Create multiple buttons dynamically in MIT App Inventor

Tags: app-inventor

I am searching a way to programmatically create buttons in a vertical scroll alignment layout in MIT App Inventor but unable to find proper tutorial or documents not available. Could someone highlight if it's possible.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To create components dynamically is not possible in the core system of MIT App Inventor, but there is an extension you can use, which is able to do it, see here [Dynamic Components Extension (for all App Inventor components)](https://community.kodular.io/t/free-dynamic-components-extension-for-all-ai-components/50789?u=taifun) by Yusuf Cihan

See the [App Inventor Extensions document](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/other/extensions.html) about how to use an App Inventor Extension.
[For the extensions directory see here](https://puravidaapps.com/extensions.php).